# Dropdown menu not showing its Items on Click in ASP.NET MVC5 View

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

When I click the dropdown menu, then it should show its items but it don't. I know not why this is happening. Kindly tell me where I should make the changes to improve it

ul+li dropdown-menu not showing its items

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List Item 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List Item 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List Item 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Below given dropdown-menu is showing its items then how I can create Mega-dropdown menu with select and option tags. kindly guide me

```
<div class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <select name="colour" class="form-control">
            <option>Please Select</option>
            <option>red</option>
            <option>orange</option>
            <option>blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are basically used just to list the elements.

In order to make your dropdown list work, you can use ***select*** and ***option*** HTML tags instead of ***ul*** and ***li***

Comment: Kindly review the question again, I updated it with the second dropdown-menu

Answer (score 2):

You can use optgroup tag for multi level dropdown list. Its easy to implement and you can get lots of articles to aid you.

Comment: can you share a sample please, I'll be thankful to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone modify it to create mega dropdown-menu, please add more information to it. Your cooperation will be appreciated :-)

```
<div class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <select name="Items" class="form-control">
            <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option>Item 1</option>
                <option>Item 2</option>
                <option>Item 3</option>
                <option>Item 4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 2">
                <option>Item 1</option>
                <option>Item 2</option>
                <option>Item 3</option>
                <option>Item 4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <option>Clothes</option>
            <option>Foods</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```